# Show that $\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^n[(\ell+1)^{p+1} - \ell^{p+1}] = (n+1)^{p+1} -1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In the solutions of my math exercice, there is the following equality :

$$\sum_{\ell=1}^{n} (\ell+1)^{p+1} - \ell^{p+1} = (n+1)^{p+1} -1 $$

But I don't how do you go from the first to the second. It surely has to do with the binomial theorem, but after trying, I don't see any equality. Thanks for your help.

Btw: do you know a website where you can compare two mathematical expression, see if they are equal, how do you go from one to the other and that includes math symbols like sums, integrals, and so on?

Comment: It telescopes .

Comment: Another hint: $(1+1)^{p+1} - 2^{p+1} =0$

Comment: More generally, $$\sum_{\ell=1}^n(a_{\ell+1}-a_\ell)=a_{n+1}-a_1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{l=1}^{n} [(l+1)^{p+1} - l^{p+1}] = [\color{red}{2^{p+1}}-1]+[3^{p+1}\color{red}{-2^{p+1}}]+\cdots+[\color{red}{n^{p+1}}-(n-1)^{p+1}]+[(n+1)^{p+1}\color{red}{-n^{p+1}}]\\=(n+1)^{p+1}-1$$

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think to do it that way. Thanks a lot !